# product not saving after upgrading to Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

Recently I upgraded My Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3, After upgrading I configured Multi Source Inventory, It is working as expected while creating new products (and products created after upgradation). But it is throwing error while updating old products (which were created before upgrading to 2.3).

Below error is thrown by system while saving old products-

> The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again.

In `exception.log` there is below log for the error-

> main.CRITICAL: The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try
>   again. {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): The
>   stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. at
>   `/magento_root/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php:187,`
>   `Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0):` Could
>   not save Source Item at
>   `/magento_root/vendor/magento/module-inventory/Model/SourceItem/Command/Handler/SourceItemsSaveHandler.php:78`,
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`magento_db`.`inventory_source_item`, CONSTRAINT
>   `INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_INVENTORY_SOURCE_SOURCE_CODE`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`source_code`) REFERENCES `inventory_source`
>   (`source_code`) ON DEL), query was: INSERT INTO inventory_source_item
>   (`source_code`, `sku`, `quantity`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `quantity` = VALUES(`quantity`), `status` =
>   VALUES(`status`) at
>   /magento_root/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235,
>   PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`magento_root`.`inventory_source_item`, CONSTRAINT
>   `INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_INVENTORY_SOURCE_SOURCE_CODE`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`source_code`) REFERENCES `inventory_source`
>   (`source_code`) ON DEL) at
>   /magento_root/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"}
>   []

Does anyone have idea about this issue?

Comment: please check your log files

Comment: did you checked after indexing ?

Comment: Issue seems must be because of reindexing, please reset reindex and re-index again.

Comment: @AasimGoriya I tried reset and reindex again, still same result

Comment: I am facing a similar issue after upgrading 2.2.6 to 2.3.1.

Comment: I had the same problem (not being able to save a stock item). It worked fine with only one website, but when I added a second, the problem started (deleting the second website and it worked fine again). After a lot of research, I found that the second website was not listed in the following table:
inventory_stock_sales_channel
I added the website and it works just fine (also makes sense why it didn't before).
I added a third website (just to test). Same problem, same fix.
I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: any updates on it? I have same error.

Comment: @RakeshDonga No, I didn't got any solution yet

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution if you are not planning to use MSI you can simply disable all modules related to it by using below

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
```

As you are reading this you probably planning to use MSI so here's how you can solve it :),

In MSI `inventory_source_item` table is responsible for inventory management. Make sure that products whic you migrated to **2.3.x** are exists in table.

If not then try to add those manually for a particular SKU like,

Enter in `inventory_source_item` with your desired qty and with source code.

See below screenshot.

[image]

Here I've no qty so data is like **0.0000** you can add your desired qty.

**Note :** if you've multiple source then add new entry to that table with different source.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in magento 2.4. Can you please suggest me how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the search engine value in the admin configuration by following the below steps

1. Choose **Stores-> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search**
2. Choose **MYSQL** value in the **Search Engine** dropdown
3. Save config and flush cache

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after running the following commands works well:

```
rm -rf generated/*
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I had tried this commands but nothing worked

Comment: You should setup the inventory source for the product. See: Stores/Inventory/Source and Catalog/Inventory/Products/Sources

Comment: It is all working fine for the new products, issue is only for the products which were created before upgradation

Comment: Please make sure to assign all websites to a stock before running the indexer. At least all websites with a product assigned.

Answer (score 1):

tray this in your database

INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`website_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,0,'Default');

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Index product price into Update By Schedule.

[image]

I found that plugin tries to reindex prices in trunsaction.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. There was an entry missing in cataloginventory_stock

**Please try it**

```
INSERT INTO cataloginventory_stock (stock_id, website_id, stock_name) VALUES ('1', '1', 'default');
```